# Redirect per-app DNS requests at the ALE_CONNECT_REDIRECT_V4 layer using WFP

Tags: windows, winapi, windows-firewall, wfp

I am trying to redirect DNS requests on a per-app basis using WFP (Windows Filtering Platform). I want to redirect to a public DNS server - not a local proxy. I have a callout driver at the `ALE_CONNECT_REDIRECT_V4` layer. When I trace DNS requests at this layer, i can see them going out just fine.

However, when i rewrite the DNS server ip (using `INETADDR_SET_ADDRESS`) to another public server such as `1.1.1.1` (i'm only rewriting to public servers, not a local proxy) I see the rewritten DNS requests leaving on wireshark and also their responses coming in, successfully -- yet the application whose DNS i'm rewriting does not receive those DNS responses - it fails to resolve the hostname.

I have disabled the DNS cache so that the DNS requests come directly from the application, rather than the svchost.exe process.

Why is this? Do I have to somehow also hook incoming packets and restore the DNS server to the one the application expects? I'm at a loss.

Comment: What's your classify function look like? I just wrote a minimal test driver and it works fine on Windows 10 x64.

Comment: @luke what do you mean it works fine? The app accepts the DNS request? I just got confirmation from Microsoft that I need to use the datagram packet layer instead as the app will indeed reject the DNS as its not the expected server ip (though the tcp/ip stack does accept the dns request/response). So they suggested I rewrite both outgoing and incoming at the packet layer itself... You're saying it works for you just using connection redirect?! The app actually accepts it?

Comment: Doh, I only tested against nslookup. I guess it depends on how the DNS lookup is coded in the particular application; presumably nslookup isn't verifying that the response is coming from the address it (thinks it) sent to.

Comment: @Luke that's interesting, i checked it with 'ping' and it failed, but i never tested it with 'nslookup' - that's very curious if ti works with that! :) Could i see your classifyFn ? (i could post mine too, but it's a lot of work to extract out the code cos it does a tonne of other stuff as well, heh, but if you really want it i could make an effort to do that too :D)

Comment: https://pastebin.com/khGcGd52 I assume that for UDP DNS requests the default resolver checks that the address of a response matches the address of a request. nslookup probably handles DNS stuff itself and doesn't check this. It would be interesting to test this with TCP DNS requests; I would expect it to work with those since there's no need to match requests with responses since it happens on a dedicated communication channel.

Comment: @Luke awesome thanks, did you test it with ping and other apps? does it fail then? i.e it only works with nslookup?

Comment: Only works with nslookup

Comment: So DnsQuery() succeeds when using TCP and times out when using UDP. I guess you'd have to intercept inbound datagrams and modify the source address.

Comment: Sorry to hijack this thread, but NextDNS is searching for a Windows developer that would be interested for a mission to implement a WFP callout driver for our Windows DoH client. If you Luke or @horseguy are interested, please ping us at (team at nextdns dot io).

Comment: @OlivierPoitrey The solution to this problem was acdtually MUCH more involved than found in the accepted answer on this quesion. I actuallly had to manipulalte packets on the IP layer, don't go down the wrong path and play with the `ALE_CONNECT` etc layers, it just leads straight to hell and wasted time.

Comment: @horseyguy thanks for you response. Did you end up with a working solution?

Comment: @OlivierPoitrey yep! but it has some drawbacks. In order to redirect DNS on a per-app basis you need to disable the 'dnscache' service, which is responsible for making DNS requests on behallf of the app. Unfortunately, doing this also breaks the netbios/smb lookup as the dnscache service was responsible for this too. So things lilke network drives and so on may break. Also, you have to keep track of outgoing packets so you know to match the incoming ones at the ip layer and rewrite those too. The layers you care about are `IPPACKET_OUTBOUND` and `IPPACKET_INBOUND`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After trying this out for myself, yes, for DNS traffic over UDP you have to intercept the inbound datagrams and modify the source address using the clone-drop-reinject method. DNS traffic over TCP is unaffected since it is a connection-based protocol whereas UDP is connectionless.

Full minimal working driver code: https://pastebin.com/tCHqNnJH

Relevant extract:

```
void UpdateIpv4HeaderChecksum(PIPV4_HEADER IpHeader, UINT32 IpHeaderSize)
{
    UINT32 Checksum = 0;
    UINT32 WordCount = IpHeaderSize / sizeof(UINT16);
    UINT16* Header = (UINT16*)IpHeader;

    IpHeader->Checksum = 0;

    for (UINT8 WordIndex = 0; WordIndex < WordCount; WordIndex++)
    {
        Checksum += Header[WordIndex];
    }

    Checksum = (Checksum & 0x0000ffff) + (Checksum >> 16);
    Checksum += (Checksum >> 16);

    IpHeader->Checksum = (UINT16)~Checksum;
}

void NTAPI DriverDatagramDataInjectComplete(
    _In_ void* context,
    _Inout_ NET_BUFFER_LIST* netBufferList,
    _In_ BOOLEAN dispatchLevel
)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(context);
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(dispatchLevel);

    if (!NT_SUCCESS(netBufferList->Status))
    {
        DoTraceMessage(Default, "DriverDatagramDataInjectComplete() Status=%!STATUS!", netBufferList->Status);
    }

    FwpsFreeCloneNetBufferList(netBufferList, 0);
}

void NTAPI DriverDatagramDataClassify(
    _In_ const FWPS_INCOMING_VALUES* inFixedValues,
    _In_ const FWPS_INCOMING_METADATA_VALUES* inMetaValues,
    _Inout_opt_ void* layerData,
    _In_opt_ const void* classifyContext,
    _In_ const FWPS_FILTER* filter,
    _In_ UINT64 flowContext,
    _Inout_ FWPS_CLASSIFY_OUT* classifyOut
)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(layerData);
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(classifyContext);
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(filter);
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(flowContext);

    UINT32 RemoteAddress = inFixedValues->incomingValue[FWPS_FIELD_DATAGRAM_DATA_V4_IP_REMOTE_ADDRESS].value.uint32;
    UINT16 RemotePort = inFixedValues->incomingValue[FWPS_FIELD_DATAGRAM_DATA_V4_IP_REMOTE_PORT].value.uint16;
    IF_INDEX InterfaceIndex = inFixedValues->incomingValue[FWPS_FIELD_DATAGRAM_DATA_V4_INTERFACE_INDEX].value.uint32;
    IF_INDEX SubInterfaceIndex = inFixedValues->incomingValue[FWPS_FIELD_DATAGRAM_DATA_V4_SUB_INTERFACE_INDEX].value.uint32;
    FWP_DIRECTION Direction = inFixedValues->incomingValue[FWPS_FIELD_DATAGRAM_DATA_V4_DIRECTION].value.uint32;

    FWPS_PACKET_INJECTION_STATE PacketInjectionState = FwpsQueryPacketInjectionState(g_InjectionHandle, layerData, NULL);

    classifyOut->actionType = FWP_ACTION_PERMIT;
    classifyOut->rights |= FWPS_RIGHT_ACTION_WRITE;

    if ((Direction == FWP_DIRECTION_INBOUND) && (PacketInjectionState == FWPS_PACKET_NOT_INJECTED) && (RemotePort == DNS_PORT) && (RemoteAddress == DNS_HOST_REDIRECT))
    {
        UINT32 IpHeaderSize = inMetaValues->ipHeaderSize;
        UINT32 TransportHeaderSize = inMetaValues->transportHeaderSize;

        PNET_BUFFER NetBuffer = NET_BUFFER_LIST_FIRST_NB((PNET_BUFFER_LIST)layerData);
        NdisRetreatNetBufferDataStart(NetBuffer, IpHeaderSize + TransportHeaderSize, 0, NULL);

        PNET_BUFFER_LIST NetBufferList = NULL;
        NTSTATUS Status = FwpsAllocateCloneNetBufferList(layerData, NULL, NULL, 0, &NetBufferList);
        if (!NT_SUCCESS(Status))
        {
            DoTraceMessage(Default, "FwpsAllocateCloneNetBufferList() Status=%!STATUS!", Status);
        }

        NdisAdvanceNetBufferDataStart(NetBuffer, IpHeaderSize + TransportHeaderSize, FALSE, NULL);

        if (!NetBufferList)
        {
            return;
        }

        DoTraceMessage(Default, "Modify DNS response");

        NetBuffer = NET_BUFFER_LIST_FIRST_NB(NetBufferList);

        PIPV4_HEADER IpHeader = NdisGetDataBuffer(NetBuffer, sizeof(IPV4_HEADER), NULL, 1, 0);
        IpHeader->SourceAddress = DNS_HOST_ORIGINAL;
        UpdateIpv4HeaderChecksum(IpHeader, sizeof(IPV4_HEADER));

        Status = FwpsInjectTransportReceiveAsync(g_InjectionHandle, NULL, NULL, 0, AF_INET, inMetaValues->compartmentId, InterfaceIndex, SubInterfaceIndex, NetBufferList, DriverDatagramDataInjectComplete, NULL);
        if (!NT_SUCCESS(Status))
        {
            DoTraceMessage(Default, "FwpsInjectTransportReceiveAsync() Status=%!STATUS!", Status);
            FwpsFreeCloneNetBufferList(NetBufferList, 0);
        }

        classifyOut->actionType = FWP_ACTION_BLOCK;
        classifyOut->rights &= ~FWPS_RIGHT_ACTION_WRITE;
        classifyOut->flags |= FWPS_CLASSIFY_OUT_FLAG_ABSORB;
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow! THis will be incredible useful, but how did you manage to only modify the inbound packets associated with the DNS on the given app?

Comment: I didn't, I modify all inbound DNS traffic from port 53. To limit it to specific apps you could associate some context with the data flow and check that in the datagram callout to figure out what to do.

Comment: oh that's interrsting, so if i associate context with the data flow in the connect_redirect layer classifyn, then that context will also be availalbe in the datagram_packet layer when looking at incoming packets?